# Returns More Than Requested Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this PL/SQL Function:

```
Create Or Replace Function mostMealOrders
Return varchar
Is

name_phone varchar(200) := ' ';

Cursor c1 Is
        Select acctid  
        From MealOrder Natural Join Customer
        Group By acctid
        Having Count(*) >= All (Select Count(*)
                                From MealOrder
                                Group By acctid);

Begin
        For acctNum in c1
        Loop
                Select (name || ' ' || phone || ', ')
                Into name_phone
                From Customer
                Where acctid = acctNum.acctid;
        End Loop
        Return name_phone;
End;
/
Show Errors;
```

When I run the above code I receive this error:

```
exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

The subquery tries to find the `acctId` with the most number of orders from the `OrderTable`.

The subquery is returning more than one acctid and therefore I believe that is why I am getting the error. Does anyone know how I can grab the name and phone of all the `acctid's` returned from the subquery as I am trying to do in the outer query?

Comment: You could use a [cursor](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php). But that is not always an optimal solution. If your aim is to perform an update based on each value, you might be able to do it with just a bulk `update` statement.

Comment: So would I put all of the acctid into the cursor and then loop through them and concatenate all of the customer name and phone into a string inside of the Begin?

Comment: I don't know from your question what you are doing with each value. Is the purpose to just concatenate it to one single value? Could you also show that part of the code, if you have it?

Comment: Yes the purpose is to concatenate it into a single value. I updated my code above to include the cursor.

Comment: I believe the above code is working except it is overriding the name_phone inside of the for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cursor, like this:

```
FOR rec in (
    Select (name || ' ' || phone || ',') AS name_phone
    From Customer
    Where acctid in (Select acctid    
                     From OrderTable Natural Join Customer
                     Group By acctid
                     Having Count(*) >= All (
                                Select Count(*)
                                From OrderTable
                                Group By acctid))
) LOOP
     -- do something with rec.name_phone
     dbms_output.put_line(rec.name_phone);
END LOOP;
```

If however, you are looking for a loop that concatenates all retrieved strings to one long string, then use the [`LISTAGG`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php) function:

```
Select LISTAGG (name || ' ' || phone, ',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name, phone)
Into name_phone
From Customer
Where acctid in (Select acctid    
                 From OrderTable Natural Join Customer
                 Group By acctid
                 Having Count(*) >= All (
                            Select Count(*)
                            From OrderTable
                            Group By acctid))
```

Comment: Would the LISTAGG go in the begin block and then I wouldn't use a cursor?

Comment: If the second query solves your issue, you don't need a cursor. Depending on what you want to happen with the output of this query you may need to include it in your PL/SQL, but possibly you don't even need PL/SQL in the end, and can just do it as a single SQL statement. It all depends on what else you need to do.

Comment: Yes the second query worked! Thank you! Can you please explain the Within Group statement?

Comment: I provided a link in my answer on `LiSTAGG`. But in essence, the function is an aggregation function, like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`. So the output is reduced to a single record. Contrary to `SUM`, `COUNT` ...etc, this function needs to know in which order to accumulate the individual values, as it influences the result. That is why you also need to specify the `WITHIN GROUP` clause. It then concatenates values in that order, using the second argument as separator.

Comment: Oh ok, this makes sense now! Thank you so much for the help and the explanation!